# Eloquent query relation laravel

Tags: laravel

I have this database structure, I trying to query all the redeems with stores and store's district, so far I can only get redeems with relation to stores

```php
$redeems = Redeem::with('user', 'store')->get();
```

`districts`

| id | district |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | District1 |
| 2 | District2 |

`stores`

| id | store | ditrict_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Store1 | 1 |
| 2 | Store2 | 2 |

`redeems`

| id | store_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |

How can I get the district querying from redeems?

Comment: try nested $redeems = Redeem::with(['user', 'store.districts'])->get();

Comment: If the relation is `redeem -> store -> district` then you would have to do `with('user', 'store', 'store.district')`. Have in mind that when you use `with`, each parameter you write must be the relation name written in the model. More info about [Nested Eager Loading here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#nested-eager-loading)